# Some questions about using Vuex on NUXT (Should I use Vuex)

Tags: performance, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I like the framework of NUXT very much， But it also brings me some troubles Because we do not know much about the bottom implementation and operating principle of NUXT.
About the following four issues, I hope to get a little inspiration from you

I use NUXT2

- Will using Vuex reduce performance?
- Will Vuex run on the server? and will vuex data be downloaded from the server to the client?
- Does the use of Vuex increase the memory?
- The same state, what is the difference between storing in vuex and storing in components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should focus on a single question and show some effort on SO.
I will still answer some of your questions here.

1. Yes/No (depends how you use it, and if you do things well overall)
2. Yes
3. Yes, but it also solves a very specific problem. It's like asking: "Is using a car a more polluting solution than walking? Yes, but at the same time you cannot cover 400km by foot in a few hours".
   Again, it is more powerful but also adding JS obviously. Even tho you can totally optimize that in a lot of ways.
4. Quite a broad question. Check Vuex's documentation to learn more about why to use a state store and what benefits it does bring to the table.

---